# how to access value which passed through url?

Tags: php

I have trying to access value of variable from one page to another by using following code:-

page1.php

```
<td>
echo $var12=$row['p_id'];
echo '<a href=receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id=",$var12,">Received</a>';
</td>
```

receive_branch_confirmation.php

```
<?php echo $_GET['prop_id']; ?>
```

My previous error solved but now it is just print **",$var12,"**
please tell me where is my mistake

Comment: changes prop_id=",$var12," to prop_id=".$var12." and also get with variable prop_id.

Comment: try `$_GET['prop_id']`

Comment: To see what parameters and values are actually transferred, use `var_dump($_GET);` (resp. $_POST or $_COOKIE)

Comment: @RakeshSharma thanks it removes my error but on next page it print variable insted of its value i mean it print  ",$var12,"

Comment: If that really is `page1.php` how is it not just a load of errors? You're not stepping into PHP before the echo, you're attempting to interpolate a variable into a `'` denoted string and I've no idea what you're attempting with those commas - unless it's supposed to be `'.$var12.'`

Comment: @SmitSaraiya. provided with an explanation. Have a look and and share thought.

Comment: @SmitSaraiya. Updated with another scenario. Try and let me know if you face and hindrance.

Comment: Becasue you are echo echo $_GET['var12']; . you need to echo echo $_GET['prop_id'];

Comment: @SmitSaraiya. You have not concatenated the strings properly and i have rectified in my reply what is your error. You no need to close up a php and then place the a tag and then open up php tag. You can do it in the same php tags by echo statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using echo for displaying the a tag you no need to use echo or close and open php tags.

It is enough if you concatenate the variable that you are going to send.

```
$var12 = '2';
echo '<a href="receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id='.$var12.'">Received</a>';
```

Then your URL will look like as follows

```
http://domain.com/receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id=2
```

And in the `receive_branch_confirmation.php` you can access the variable passed with the help of `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST`

```
<?php 
echo 'Request Value: '.$prop_id = $_REQUEST['prop_id']; // this will result the output as 2
echo '<br>';
echo 'Get Value'.$prop_id = $_GET['prop_id']; // this will result the output as 2
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Request Value: 2
Get Value: 2
```

**Another Example:**

If the URL is `http://domain.com/page.php?var1=apple`

then if you need to access the variable as follows in `page.php`.

```
<?php
$u1 = $_GET['var1'];
$u2 = $_REQUEST['var1'];
echo $u1; //would output "apple"
echo $u2; //would output "apple"
?>
```

Comment: I got my mistake and thanks for explanation it helps me further also

Answer (score 1):

Try this in html

```
<td>
 <a href="receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id="<?php echo $var12;?>>Received</a>
</td>
```

in php side

```
<?php 
 echo $_GET['prop_id'];
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

page1.php

```
    <td>
   <?php echo '<a href=receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id='.$var12.'>Received</a>'; ?>
    </td>
```

receive_branch_confirmation.php

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['prop_id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<a href="receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id=<?php echo $var12; ?>">Received</a>
```

in html page and

```
<?php 
echo $_GET['prop_id'];
?>
```

in php page

> and always try to separate html from PHP

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your page1.php as below

```
  echo '<a href="receive_branch_confirmation.php?prop_id='.$var12.'">Received</a>';
```

and get it like this

```
      <?php 
echo $_GET['prop_id'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the $_GET value.

```
    <?php 
echo $_GET['prop_id'];
?>
```

Now it's looking for the prop_id instead of the value